# How to sketch the given vector field and its field lines?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-fields

Let $F(x,y)=\cos y\hat{i} + \cos x\hat{j}$. Then its vector lines satisy $-\sin x+C =\sin y$ or $\sin x + \sin y = C$. First, I try to guess how it looks like by considering $\cos(t)$ is positive, decreasing when $t \in [0,\pi/2]$ and it is negative, decreasing when $t \in [0,\pi/2]$ and so on. However, it is hard to get an appropriate graph. Then I try to guess how vector lines look like but  $\sin x + \sin y = C$ is also hard to imagine.

So, how can I sketch the graph of $F$ and its vector lines?

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be a comment but for some strange reason, I cannot input this correctly through the comment box.

---

I don't know what are vectors lines. It seems your vector lines ($\sin x + \sin y = C $ ) are the [orthogonal trajectories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory) for the family of 
[streamlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines#Streamlines) 
/ 
[fieldlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_line) associated with vector field $F = (\cos(y),\cos(x))$.

On [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), you can plot the streamlines of $F$ using the command `StreamPlot[{Cos[y],Cos[x]},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]`. 
To obtain the orthogonal trajectories, you need to manually rotate the vector field by $90^\circ$. i.e use the command `StreamPlot[{-Cos[x],Cos[y]},{x,-3,3},{y,-3,3}]` instead.

If you have Mathematica, there are more powerful variants of this sort of plot. Other CAS should have similar functionalities but I don't know the details.